# Syntax error on getting multiple range VBA

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

Here is part of my code:

```
For n = 0 To maxCol Step 1

studentRange = ws.Range(Columns(n) & curRow Columns(n) & classRange)
totalStudents = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(studentRange)
newSheet.Range("A" & activeRow).Offset(columnoffset:=activeCol).Value = totalStudents

Next n
Loop
```

What I am trying to do is to get all the number of students that take subject from each class (class on the column (n)). I have been getting syntax error on the third line of the code - beginning with studentRange, and also a type mismatch on the fourth line. What I am trying to get is the range from that particular school hence why I need two ranges - like A1:B40)

I am very new to VBA and have been trying to solve this but still no luck.

Comment: `Columns(n)` there's no column zero...

Comment: ^^^ Once you fix that, I'm guessing the first line should be `Set studentRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(curRow, n), ws.Cells(classRange, n))`.